# Biblatex school year 1987/1988 with slash as date

Tags: biblatex, date

School years are at least in some areas traditionally written with slashes, eg. "1987/1988". However, the Biblatex uses the slash in the date field to represent ranges, eg. date={1987/1988} → "1987–1988". Is there a way to get a "1987/1988" in the relevant cases while keeping the "1987–1988" format for ranges in general? For example, @thesis could have "/", otherwise "–". Or somehow make date={1987\addslash1988} or the like not throw an error?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{JohnThesis,
        author = {John Author},
        title = {A thesis},
        date = {2007/2008},
    }
@thesis{JaneThesis,
        author = {Jane Author},
        title = {A thesis},
        date = {2007\addslash2008},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, a quick but little bit dirty fix could be using the `year` field instead of `date`. It accepts slashes. Just try `year = {2007/2008}`: https://i.imgur.com/iEeoUcb.png

Comment: Hi, lukeflo! I didn't know that and can definitely work with that. Thank you for the super quick reply :)

Comment: Happy that I could help. I formulate it as answer, so you can mark the question as solved if wanted.

Comment: Well, there's still the question of a completely proper solution, since the date field is usually recommended over the “legacy” year field in biblatex. For now, your solution is def what I'm using.

Comment: Thats correct. But the recommendation relies on the additional possibilities the `date` field offers (described in § 2.3.8 and 2.3.9 of `biblatex` doc). As long as you simply need years there is no difference. It also depends on the used bib-style. In my academic discipline and the corresponding bib-styles, months and days are not printed in the bibliography. Thus, I personally prefer using `year` just to keep it simple and don't need to handle unnecessary complex `date` fields which have to many informations for my layout needs :)

Comment: `biblatex`'s `date` fields only accept ISO8601-compatible input and will always treat the contents as such. In ISO8601 the slash is a range separator, so that `2007/2008` means "2007 to 2008". The output is governed by various options and commands, but will generally give you something along  the lines of "2007 - 2008" with some sort of dash. It is possible to code stuff so that the output shows "2007/2008" for subsequent years and "2007-2009" for longer ranges. See https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/issues/133 (discussion in German). ...

Comment: ... For a quick one-off `year` along with an appropriate `sortyear` value (because non-numeric `year` fields may not sort correctly) is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hinted that your formatting choice would only be relevant for the class `@thesis`. The question, then, becomes:

> How to make it so that `biblatex` marks *date ranges by a slash* **iff** the class is `@thesis`; and otherwise use the *default en-dash*?

There's a **proper** way to do that, by using the appropriate commands built into `biblatex`.
From [3.12.3 of the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=132):

> `\bibdaterangesep`: The language specific separator to be used for date ranges. Defaults to `\textendash` for all date formats apart from *ymd* which defaults to a `\slash`.

We want to define `\bibdaterangesep` conditionally: **If** the class is `@thesis`, it should be realized as `\slash`, **otherwise** it defaults to `\textendash`.

Note that the documentation suggests to redefine this command by wrapping the change in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{...}` (or your relevant language). This is because `\bibdaterangesep` and friends are language-specific formatting commands.

Here's a MWE, slightly adapted to show the difference between `@thesis` and other classes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{JohnThesis,
        author = {John Author},
        title = {A thesis},
        date = {2007/2008},
    }
@article{JaneArticle,
        author = {Jane Author},
        title = {Not a thesis},
        date = {2007/2008},
        journaltitle = {Dates and Punctuation Studies},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
\renewcommand*{\bibdaterangesep}{%
  \ifentrytype{thesis}
    {\slash}              % if @thesis, \slash
    {\textendash}}}       % otherwise, keep the default
    
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: There you go with a elaborated and perfectly fitting answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, too kind :)

Comment: Thanks, marquinho, especially for the generous clarifications! I got it to work after a minor hiccup (while I'm loading "slovenian" for polyglossia, I need to use "slovene" for biblatex). It's a bit cleaner with no sorting warnings, though one needs to remember to set the language appropriately on documents in a different language (which is not immediately obvious). A more direct control would be better still (who knows when the thesis : other dichotomy will turn on me), but I imagine this is about the best one can do with the date field. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to use the `year` field instead of `date`, since the first accepts slashes:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @thesis{JohnThesis,
        author = {John Author},
        title = {A thesis},
        date = {2007/2008},
    }
    @thesis{JaneThesis,
        author = {Jane Author},
        title = {A thesis},
        year = {2007/2008},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: year with slashed]

*Note*: This could lead to some incorrectly sorted entries, but in most cases works well.